# AWS DMS - Error - "AWS Account owning the Role must match the caller of the API"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I am trying to create a destination in AWS DMS for an S3 and I am getting this message "**AWS Account owning the Role must match the caller of the API**", I searched for this error and could not find what it refers to. Any idea what I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

,I got this error too, and the mistake I made was to add the s3 bucket arn into the Service Role ARN rather than the IAM role ARN. See the AWS docs below to create a policy, attach it to a role, and use the role ARN. This worked for me.

[https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-dms-target/#:~:text=1.%20Open%20the%20AWS%20DMS%20console%2C%20and%20then,copied%20into%20the%20Service%20Access%20Role%20ARN%20field](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-dms-target/#:%7E:text=1.%20Open%20the%20AWS%20DMS%20console%2C%20and%20then,copied%20into%20the%20Service%20Access%20Role%20ARN%20field)

Answer (score 0):

double check if you have the correct service_access_role_arn set.